# How can i check page is going to refresh in "beforeunload" event in angular5

Tags: angular5

i am trying to put logic when user close the browser/tab then i need to clear the local session. so i have used `beforeunload` event. The problem is that it's getting called on both browser close as well as on page refresh. and i don't have to clear session on refresh it should be on close.
i tried to check only by using `clientY` and `pageY` but it's not working for me.
also i tried with the below code to identify browser is going to refresh or not and set the flag value and use it in `beforeunload` event. but it's getting called after `beforeunload` event

```
this.subscription = this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
 this.browserRefresh = !this.router.navigated;
  if(this.browserRefresh)
  {
   console.log("browserRefresh");
  }
  else
  {
   console.log(" else browserRefresh");
  }
```

}
 });

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
    beforeunload($event) {

    console.log("clear session");

}
```

Please suggest if i am using wrong event for the task or suggest me the correct way to this. i checked few links suggested but nothing is helping.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this Hope so it can work

```
@HostListener('window:unload', ['$event'])
    beforeunload($event) {

    console.log("clear session");

}
```